# Should I use a volume group or a logical volume for /home on LVM?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I'm setting up Lucid on a new laptop and I'd like to use LVM - partly for flexibility and partly to make it easy to move /home to a new distro if needed.

Should I be setting up /home on it's own VG (initially containing a single PV) or is it OK to add all PVs to a single VG and to slice off a LV for /home?

It feels to me like one VG for /home and one VG for everything else is the best answer for keeping /home safe or moving it at a later date, but does that limit my flexibility for resizing things later?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole point of volume groups is to contain several logical volumes. The only reason I can think of to use separate volume groups is if they must be kept on different (sets of) physical volumes (for example, I have a desktop machine with two hard drives and three volume groups: one RAID1-ed between the two drives, and one on each drive).

If you only intend to run Linux on that machine, make a single partition on the hard disk, use that partition as a PV, make a VG containing just that PV, and create one LV per filesystem (root, home, swap).