# Can I Install Ubuntu to a machine from a full USB flash drive installation?

Tags: live-usb

I have a 16 gig flash drive with an installation of Ubuntu on it with a bunch of programs and built software. I know that normally a bootable version of Ubuntu will have a thing on the desktop to install to the hard drive. How do I replicate this full USB installation on a computer?

Comment: This might be a help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20460/move-installation-to-new-disk as it is a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Install the following packages:

- For Ubuntu:

  - `ubiquity-frontend-gtk`
  - `ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu`
- For Kubuntu:

  - `ubiquity-frontend-kde`
  - `ubiquity-slideshow-kubuntu`
- For Xubuntu:

  - `ubiquity-frontend-gtk`
  - `ubiquity-slideshow-xubuntu`

Then put a launcher to `ubiquity` on your desktop and you are ready to install Ubuntu from your stick at will.